# Updating Checked ListBox values in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Lets say I have a DataBase table  that associates an Id with multiple items. 
Say ID with favorite food. 
So it looks like

---

```
Id  FoodId
----------

1    1
1    54
1    543
2     42
2    4234
```

---

etc

I can select/ unselect favorite food values using my checked list box

When I update the db after I edit the items, do I go back and delete all previous entries in the table with Id 1 and then enter the whole new set or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM favfood
WHERE id=@Id and foodid not in(new_list_of_food_ids)

// serialized new_list_of_food_ids

INSERT INTO favfood(id,foodid)
(SELECT @Id, [int] 
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfInt/int',1)
WITH ([int]  int '.')
where [int] not in (select foodid from favfood where id=@Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be your approach. But it is also the slowest and generates redundant database operations. The correct way would be to have the old and the new list in memory creating `delete`, `insert` statements accordingly.

1. Compare the two lists and remove all identical values from both lists.
2. Create `DELETE`statements for all remaining values in the 'old' list.
3. Create `INSERT`statements for all remaining values in the 'new' list.

Comment: well i figured a way to do all the deleting and adding in the database , no need to use lists ..